# multiple activity trouble

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to create an application that uses a main activity and 2 sub activities. The sub activities are just used to send information to the main activity. I was able to get the main activity and the first sub activity working properly. Once I added the 2nd sub activity my application would not handle it for some reason. I am unable to find out why my 2nd sub activity would not work. I thought I mimic'ed everything from my first sub activity and would have it working. But that's not the case. Anyone have an idea for something to check / try?

Comment: Found it was because I did not add the activity to my manifest and register it.

Answer (score 1):

Code would work, but it sounds like you haven't added your activities to your manifest file.

```
 <activity android:name=".MySubActivity"/>
```